# How Do I Select for Multiple Classes Using Nokogiri and Ruby

Tags: css, ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

From a table element, I would like to select all rows that have the class `even` or the class `odd`.

I tried the jQuery syntax:

```
report.css("table.data tr[class~=odd even]").each{|line| parse_line_item(line)}
```

but it threw an error, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use two selectors: `report.css("table.data tr.odd, table.data tr.even")`

The `~=` operator in a CSS attribute selector checks that the value matches a space-delimited list of classes. For instance, `tr[class~=odd]` would match `<tr class="odd">` and `<tr class="odd ball">`. However, in the specific case of the `class` attribute, the better selector is simply `tr.odd`.

If you use the `~=` operator with a space in the value (as in `tr[class~="odd even"]`, the selector will never match anything.

Comment: this works, however it gives it to me as `1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8` rather than sequentially.  is there a way to get it sequentially?

Comment: If the order matters, you could select `table.data tr[class]` to find every `tr` with any `class` attribute, then check for an exact `class` value in Ruby. It's not as succinct, but far more flexible than CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS selector you have there is not even a syntactically valid selector:

```
[class~=odd even]
```

Values that contain whitespace must always be quoted, so the correct way to write this selector would be:

```
[class~="odd even"]
```

However, this selector actually cannot ever match anything: the `[attr~=val]` attribute value selector matches ...

> [an element with the `att` attribute whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly `"val"`. If `"val"` contains whitespace, it will never represent anything (since the words are *separated* by spaces)](http://Dev.W3.Org/csswg/selectors3/#attribute-representation)

Since the words are separated by whitespace, this means they cannot ever contain whitespace themselves. But the word *you* are looking for (`"odd even"`), *does* contain whitespace, therefore it cannot ever match anything.

Presumably, what you are looking for is an `OR` combinator, but it doesn't exist. So, what you are looking for cannot be expressed with CSS selectors.

Well, actually, that's not true: it *can* be expressed with CSS selectors. You can simply use selector groups, which give you set union of the matches, which is equivalent to using an `OR` combinator:

```
table.data tr.odd, table.data tr.even
```

Remember: CSS is set-based, therefore order doesn't matter. In your case, order *does* matter, which means that CSS is really the wrong tool for the job:

```
report.xpath('//table[@class="data"]//tr[@class="odd" or @class="even"')
```

Although I must admit that I am not sure why you don't just use something like this:

```
report.css('table.data tr')
```

After all, isn't selecting all odd and all even rows the same as selecting *all* rows? I mean, what else have you got in there, irrational rows?

Comment: `tr` could be a header for example.